# Bootstrap multiselect with ajax

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-multiselect

I need to use the bootstrap multiselect with ajax, instead of bringing all options (in my case are many) in loading the page. The intention is that when the user is typing the component to be recharged from an ajax query maintaining the state of the options previously selected.

Comment: Try to google autocomplete in jQuery UI.

Comment: good suggestion, I'll see if it meets the needs. Thank U

Comment: There is a web page with good tutorials that show examples on how to use it. Hope it helps.